# What data does the Google drive app contain in an android smartphone?

Tags: internal-storage, google-play-services, google-apps

I want to delete some of my android apps data due to storage problems. I see that my Google drive app does contain a lot of data and cache. I have already deleted the cache but I am not sure if I should delete the data associated with this app because I don't want to lose any of files both in my android phone or in Google drive. What does does this app exactly contain and what I may lose on clearing this app's data?

Comment: You do know of the [Google Drive help page](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2424384?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en) along with [How to delete and restore in Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375102?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=1)

Answer (score 4):

> What does does this app exactly contain

The app's files and settings, plus the files that you have made available for offline use.

> and what I may lose on clearing this app's data?

Nothing. Only the data that were on the phone. Files that were uploaded to Google Drive wont be affected. They can only be deleted if you delete them from within the app. The app will return to the state it was in the first time you use it on the phone.